# Meaning of modified Madgwick Filter equations

Tags: rotations, quaternions

I have been implementing the algorithm in the paper titled [Design of a Modified Madgwick Filter for Quaternion-Based Orientation Estimation Using AHRS](http://www.ijcee.org/index.php?m=content&c=index&a=show&catid=96&id=1122) by Amjed S. Al-Fahoum and Momtaz S. Abadir (thank you [IJCEE](http://www.ijcee.org/) for being open access). I have been able to figure out most parts, but am confused by equations 15 to 17 on page 5 (178 in Journal). They reference [Mahoney *et al.*](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Nonlinear-Complementary-Filters-on-the-Special-Mahony-Hamel/b26c3142bc296b7642a5e5300cd53b5adf000f84), but [that paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00488376/document) is much more opaque to me. I asked the authors recently, but no response yet (if you're reading, you're welcome to answer this here for all).

The equations define $\omega_{error,t}$ as a quaternion estimate of gyroscope error, $\omega_{b,t}$ as the DC component of $\omega_{error,t}$, and $\omega_{c,t}$ as the compensated gyroscope measurement:

$\omega_{error,t} = 2.\hat{q}^*_{est,t-1} \otimes \dot{q}_{est,t} \tag{15}$

where $\hat{q}^*_{est,t-1}$ is the conjugate of the previous time's orientation, and $\dot{q}_{est,t}$ is an estimated rate of change of the orientation quaternion from the current and previous estimates.

$\omega_{b,t} = \sigma\sum{\omega_{error,t}\Delta t} \tag{16}$

where $\Delta t$ is the time since the previous estimate and $\sigma$ is a gain parameter.

$\omega_{c,t} = \omega_{b,t} - \omega_{error,t} \tag{17}$

1. Why does the error equation hava a different coefficient from [the quaternion derivative equation](https://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2012/08/24/quaternion-differentiation/) $\dot{q}=\frac12 \omega q$?
2. Why aren't the gyroscope measurements ($\omega_t$ or $\dot{q}_{\omega,t}$) explicitly included in the bias calculation?

   - This seems important since $\omega_{c,t}$ is used in place of gyroscope measurements $\omega_t$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reply from one of the authors:

> Equation 17 should read:
>   $\omega_{c,t} = \omega_{t} - \omega_{b,t} \tag{17}$

This aligns more with my expectations, but the factor of two in Equation 15 is unexpected to me. It could be absorbed into the $\sigma$ in any case, so perhaps it is just a scaling.